# conditional sum calculation in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

So I want to know the total balance owed by the students who owe $3500 or more.
This is what I try at first

> SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM STUDENT ;

It work fine, but does not meet the condition.

So i tried this

> SELECT SUM(BALANCE) FROM STUDENT
>      WHERE BALANCE >= 3500 ;

gave me the same answer so i guess it should not be right??

then i tried this

> select sum(balance > = 3500) from student ;

which gives me a syntax error.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this out:

```
SELECT SUM(BALANCE),studentNo FROM STUDENT 
group by studentNo  having SUM(BALANCE)>3500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(CASE WHEN balance >= 250 THEN balance ELSE 0 END) from student ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
select sum(balance) from (select balance from student where balance >= 3500);
```